# Is there a KDE equivalent to Zeitgeist's activity logging?

Tags: kde, logging, metadata, nepomuk, ubuntu-unity

My Googling so far has revealed that people have talked about Nepomuk supporting this kind of thing, in the abstract or in future - but so far I've been unable to find out how to use it as a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently isn't, but we are planning to do so.

The activity manager is a central service that will deal with it, but where the actual data will be located, that is a question not yet answered.

We may have even end up sharing zeitgeist with gnome (it has no gnome dependencies)

Comment: Yup - it's going to be the latter, apparently: http://seilo.geekyogre.com/2010/11/zeitgeist-coming-to-kde/

Comment: Zeitgeist is the main option for now, but we could always decide to change it eventually. That's the main reason I want everything to go through the Activity Manager service - abstraction of the backends (Nepomuk and Zeitgeist).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this will be associated with "Activity Manager", but it's not yet implemented. See [this blog comment](http://ivan.fomentgroup.org/blog/2010/11/03/activities/#comment-24088) by one of the KDE developers involved.

Answer (score 0):

Well , I can give you 100 use cases of Nepomuk for an end user. Firstly Dolphin's information panel,Search panel and Dolphin's search is completely integrated with Nepomuk. You can do content based search, file name based search using nepomuk indexed data. Along with that you can easily search for images,audio,video etc using search panel. You can rate a file,comment on it or tag it. All these things are happening because of Nepomuk only. Gwenview has also been integrated with nepomuk. There are so many other nepomuk based apps like nepoogle, notably etc. BTW I'm working on a nepomuk based resource browser called [Repontik](http://blog.6bytesmore.com/2011/12/resource-browser.html). Also in my GSoC project I had worked on integration of rekonq and konqueror with nepomuk using fancy bookmarking. Nepomuk is very powerful and we can do many apps on top of nepomuk.

Please visit http://trueg.wordpress.com/ and http://vhanda.in/blog/  to know more about nepomuk.

Comment: Zeitgeist is a bit different in that it provides _automatic_ activity logging. It has recently been hooked into Nepomuk, something which was planned for a long time.